# wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, xserver

I have been using [wkthmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert html to pdf documents on-the-fly on my linux web server.  The program originally needed X11 or similar X server to run correctly, but through many requests by developers to have this run on servers without GUI, I am pretty sure it runs a virtual X server in the [static version](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/static).  I have been using the static (stand-alone) version of the program and it works great!  I would put the executable file in a folder, and run:

```
./wkhtmltopdf file1.html file2.pdf
```

However I would like to install this program system-wide.  I used the `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` (just installed yesterday) and since I am running on a 64 bit system, I also needed `apt-get install ia32-libs`.  After installation I can find the version like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf --version
```

output:

```
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9

License:
  Copyright (C) 2008,2009 Wkhtmltopdf Authors.



  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO
  WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Authors:
  Written by Jakob Truelsen. Patches by Mário Silva, Benoit Garret and Emmanuel
  Bouthenot.
```

Now when I try to run the program installed via aptitude, I get the following error:

```
wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I guess this version is missing a virtual X server or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured out that I can simply move the static executable to the `/usr/bin/` directory and execute it from anywhere.

Answer (score 210):

or try this (from http://drupal.org/node/870058)

1. [Download wkhtmltopdf.](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) Or better install it with a package manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
   ```
2. Extract it and move it to `/usr/local/bin/`
3. Rename it to `wkhtmltopdf` so that now you have an executable at `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
4. Set permissions: `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
5. Install required support packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev
   ```
6. Check to see if it works: run

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
   ```

   If it works, then you are done. If you get the error "Cannot connect to X server" then continue to number 7.
7. We need to run it headless on a 'virtual' x server. We will do this with a package called xvfb.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xvfb
   ```
8. We need to write a little shell script to wrap wkhtmltopdf in xvfb. Make a file called `wkhtmltopdf.sh` and add the following:

   ```
   xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf "$@"
   ```
9. Move this shell script to `/usr/local/bin`, and set permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
   ```
10. Check to see if it works once again: run

    ```
    /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh http://www.google.com test.pdf
    ```

Note that http://www.google.com may throw an error like "A finished ResourceObject received a loading finished signal. This might be an indication of an iframe taking to long to load." You may want to test with a simpler page like `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: I tried that tutorial originally, and it didn't quite work, also I didn't like having to create the wrapper with symbolic link.  Like I wrote in my answer, if you just move the static executable to the `/usr/bin/` directory you can use it from anywhere.  They added a virtual x-server to static executable, so no need to make the wrapper script.

Comment: it worked for me.. in some situations. I think installing missing 32bit libraries fixed it for me - thanks for that tip

Comment: What is the statement in number 6 `If you get the error "Cannot connect to X server" then continue to number 6.` supposed to mean? I'm very confused by this. Do you mean to say to continue to number 7?

Comment: Yes, that is what is meant...the original article had mis-numbered the items. So go on to #7

Comment: thanks, renumbered..
The suggested answer should work in most cases though, so try that first

Comment: with pdfkit in python I get a Exec error when I try this :/ even though it works fine in terminal

Comment: And if you have a script with a hardcoded installation path; you can create a symlink to run the shell script. Works like a charm (y)

Answer (score 62):

This solved the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf file1.html file2.pdf
```

Comment: This is the easiest and safest approach, since the standard installation of wkhtmltopdf doesn't include the x-server.

Comment: This is how to solve "cannot connect to X server" in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: On Redhat based distros use `sudo yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` resp. `sudo dnf install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`.

Answer (score 28):

I tried to do `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` but without any success.
Instead I recommend you try:

1. Download the latest executable (.11 rc1) :

   `wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2`
2. uncompress it :

   `tar -vxf wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2`
3. rename it :

   `mv wkhtmltopdf-i386 wkhtmltopdf`
4. chmod it to executable :

   `chmod a+x wkhtmltopdf`
5. place it into /usr/bin :

   `sudo mv wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin`

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=730 seems like vs 11.0_rc1 has some issues

Comment: this worked for me but the pdf generation failed so I replaced the above instructions with `https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2`

Comment: downloading wkhtmltox-linux-amd64_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz works for me now.  For some reason the latest does not.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me: (getting latest stable version atm)
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar -vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
chmod a+x wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf
sudo mv wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 27):

Just made it:

1- To download wkhtmltopdf dependencies

`# apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`

2- Download from source

`# wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/xxx.deb`

`# dpkg -i xxx.deb`

3- Try

`# wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf`

Its working fine

It works!

Comment: I had to run `apt-get install -f` after installing the package to get the dependencies. Otherwise worked like a charm. Much prefer this method to the others described.

Comment: I agree. This solution got me to the current rev. The dpkg -i command did generate some ambiguous info but regardless, it worked:

    `wget -q http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb` followed by `sudo dpkg --install wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb`

Comment: this is still the better solution provided to this question.

Comment: I had to run `sudo mv wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin` from the `/usr/local/bin/` directory, but this worked great! I tried every other method on this page with no luck before hand..

Comment: this should get higher upvotes as a latest and simpler solution without relying other packages (which also solves 'Cannot connect to X server' problem). and I have issues with relative css path not being loaded when using xvfb.

Answer (score 16):

I found method to resolve this problem without fake X server.
In newest version of wkhtmltopdf dont need X server for work, but it no into official linux repositories.

**Solution for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) i386**

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
$ wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-i386.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-i386.deb
$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

**Solution for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) amd64**

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
$ wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

User **felixhummel** got very good solution, but repository with utilite has changed.

Comment: for some reason this was working for me and the newer version (0.13) was not thank you!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, i have tried lot of other resolution but none of them worked. As i am new to php/Laravel environment so i have no deep knowledge of these libraries & dependencies, but this solution is awesome simply saved my hours :)

Comment: Really this solution is awesome today i moved to production and got same issue, without wasting anytime i just run these solution and it worked smoothly :)

Comment: gna.org is now shut down. :(

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on Timothy's answer...

If you're a web developer looking to use wkhtmltopdf as part of your web app, you can simply install it into your `/usr/bin/` folder like so:

```
cd /usr/bin/
curl -C - -O http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2
mv wkhtmltopdf-i386 wkhtmltopdf
```

You can now run it anywhere using `wkhtmltopdf`.

I personally use the [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) library in PHP. Here is an example of how easy it is to create a PDF:

```
<?php

// Create new PDF
$pdf = new \Knp\Snappy\Pdf('wkhtmltopdf');

// Set output header
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

// Generate PDF from HTML
echo $pdf->getOutputFromHtml('<h1>Title</h1><p>Your content goes here.</p>');
```

Answer (score 11):

Update to latest wkhtmltopdf version from SourceForge (0.12 as of this writing). It does not need an X Server to run.

Example for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ cd /tmp/                                                                                                                                                                                                       
$ wget -q http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ dpkg -x wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb foo

$ echo '<p>hi</p>' | ./foo/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf - /tmp/hi.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      

$ head -n3 /tmp/hi.pdf 
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
```

Comment: I have installed 0.12.1 and it still prompts me cannot connect to X server. Am I missing something?

Comment: Tried it again and this works for me (no install, just to keep the box clean). See edit above.

Answer (score 9):

for 14.04.1-Ubuntu https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

```
wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz -O mktemp.tar.xz
tar xf mktemp.tar.xz
sudo cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
rm mktemp.tar.xz
rm wkhtmltox -rf
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo -i
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf xvfb libicu48
mv /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-origin
touch /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf && chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf && cat > /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf << END
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-origin  "\$@"
END
```

Answer (score 6):

Problem is probably in **old version of wkhtmltopdf** - version 0.9 from distribution repository require running X server, but current version - 0.12.2.1 doesnt require it - can run headless.

Download package for your distribution from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and install it - for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 6):

`wkhtmltopdf` > `0.11` doesn't have this `X-server` issue. 
So installing `0.12.2.1` on a linux server.

1. At first install xvfb server:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xvfb
   ```
2. Get needed version of wkhtmltopdf from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
3. Install wkhtmltopdf:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
   ```

   or install with `wget`

   ```
   URL='http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb'; FILE=`mktemp`; wget "$URL" -qO $FILE && sudo dpkg -i $FILE; rm $FILE
   ```
4. Install dependency (if needed):

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
5. Create symblic link in `/usr/local/bin/`:

   ```
   echo 'exec xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh >/dev/null
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
   ```
6. Now try below and it should work,

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
   ```

Answer (score 3):

**solution for Centos7**:

```
yum -y install xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi \
               xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 \
&& rpm -Uvh http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-centos7-amd64.rpm
```

We run into this problem inside docker containers and the above install has **wkhtmltopdf** with patched QT

Comment: for me URL was not working, I used this one: `sudo rpm -Uvh https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-centos7-amd64.rpm`

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use at least 0.12.2.1.

Starting from wkhtmltopdf >= 0.12.2 it doesn't require X server or emulation anymore. You can download new version from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

Just tell the Qt backend to not use X:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen wkhtmltopdf <input> <outfile.pdf>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did follow the instructions here and made wkhtmltopdf work for me but I would like to offer a bit of perspective which I discovered while doing my own little dance with `wkhtmltopdf` - `xvfb`.

This is important because the same reason that causes it to throw the infamous `cannot connect to X server` error is also causing it to run with sever limitations even if you do provide it a X server. These limitations include not being able to take multiple input sources, set header and footers, etc (check the [Reduced Functionality section of the manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)).

`wkhtmltox` by itself doesn't require a X11, however it's making use of QT libraries which do. In newever versions of wkthmltox developers made a patch for QT which allows it to run with a X11.

Currently some versions are built against patched QT and some are not. You can check your version by running `wkhtmltopds --version`. There should be a line at the end saying `Compiled against wkhtmltopdf patched qt.`

So, to conclude, if you install and use a version that uses the patched libraries it should work on a linux server without the `xvfb` server, as I can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention: your file could be `wkhtmltopdf.sh` or `wkhtmltopdf`, check it on second step

You must copy it into directory : **/usr/local/bin**, make sur it's executable and add symlink of **wkhtmltopdf.sh** like :

1- the command :

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

2 - insert the binary in directory **/usr/bin** so the browser can't have permission to execute in this directory.
You must copy the **wkhtmltopdf.sh**  to directory **/usr/local/bin** cause the browser have permission in this directory like:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

3 - After make sur the binary have permission of execution like :

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

4 - so now you can test, it's work like:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

it make download the pdf in the current directory in your terminal

5 - Optional
now you can add symlink in your directory **/usr/local/bin** like

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit Use:

```
wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

sudo mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download file from [this link](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
2. Extract it and move executable file(/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf) to `/usr/bin/`
3. Rename it to wkhtmltopdf if current name is not wkhtmltopdf. So that now you have an executable at `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
4. Set permissions: sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
5. Install required support packages. sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev
6. Now, check with `wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf`
   hint: [detail information from this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/870058)

Answer (score 0):

Just install a version 0.12.4 or higher. This seems to solve the problem.

See [How can I install the latest wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/959152/10425).

Answer (score 0):

If you config wkhtmltopdf for Rails or Somethings in Centos, you can follow these step bellow:

1. Go to https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and copied the link of rpm file.

In centos server bash.

2. `wget link_of_wkhtmltopdf_rpm.rpm`
3. `rpm -ivh link_of_wkhtmltopdf_rpm.rpm`
4. `which wkhtmltopdf`

=> You will get path of wkhtmltopdf.

5. Setup for wicked_pdf or pdfkit with path in step 4.
   This is sample config with wickedpdf. config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

   ```
   if Rails.env != "production"
       path = %x[which wkhtmltopdf].gsub(/\n/, "")
   else
       path = "path_of_wkhtmltopdf_in_step_4"
   end
   WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: path }
   ```
6. Restart server.

DONE.