# wicked_pdf does not run on Ubuntu server : wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to use wicked_pdf on my prod server but it keeps failling :

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
"/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q        "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20130709-23109-1adqx5g.html" "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20130709-23109-1ic5dbe.pdf"
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server
):
  app/controllers/contrats_controller.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/contrats_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

I tried to follow this answer : [wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server) but it still does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This post helped me to resolve my problem :
http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/generating-pdfs-in-rails-with-pdfkit-and-deploying-to-a-server/

I'm reproducing here the step from this post that helped me to install it :

```
# first, installing dependencies
sudo aptitude install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev

# for 64bits OS
wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

He also create an initializer to tell to pdfKit where it is, so this method is for wicked PDF and PDF Kit.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to add a the following to a initializers/wicked_pdf.rb file as for to get it to work: WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/path/to/wkhtmltopdf'
}

Comment: So that was my issue, it had to be in 64bit

Comment: This answer works, as the comment says, for 64 bit only.

Answer (score 11):

Resolved this problem in this tread https://stackoverflow.com/a/34947479/5320149

I found method to resolve this problem without fake X server.
In newest version of wkhtmltopdf dont need X server for work, but it no into official linux repositories.

**Solution for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) i386**

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
$ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-i386.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-i386.deb
$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

**Solution for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) amd64**

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
$ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

Comment: This answer worked for me only in an Ubuntu 32 bit version. In 64 bit found many problems when issuing command `sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-i386.deb`

Comment: @Francisco you will need to use the 64 bit package `http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb`

Comment: Thanks @tobygriffin still have to fix staging server, so I'm giving it a shot.

Comment: gna.org is shut down

Answer (score 8):

1. Verify you have `xvfb` installed, or install it using `apt-get
   install xvfb`.
2. Create a file called `wkhtmltopdf.sh` and add the following:

   ```
   xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf $*
   ```

   Change the dimensions (640x480x16) to match whatever virtual screen parameters you want it to emulate.
3. Move the shell script to `/usr/bin`, and set permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
   ```
4. Optionally, you can add a symbolic link in your project directory:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh wkhtmltopdf
   ```

See [this](http://popthestash.com/2012/07/24/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-ubuntu-server/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64820/wkhtmltopdf-wkhtmltoimage-cannot-connect-to-x-server) for reference.

Comment: It seems you can do it without xvfb