# KnpSnappyBundle - stderr: "wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server " stdout: ""

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use the [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) to create PDF files from twig templates.

I've followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server) to install `wkhtmltopdf` and it works when I do:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

but when I try to create a PDF file from a controller:

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
$this->renderView('AcmePDFBundle:Default:template.html.twig'),
'../app/var/PDFfiles/PDF.pdf'
);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
request.CRITICAL: RuntimeException: The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server
"
stdout: ""
command: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy532ca2272fba44.73835084.html' '../app/var/files/PDF.pdf'. (uncaught exception) at /home/me/MyServer/project/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php line 304 [] []
```

Any idea of how to solve it?

This is my configuration for KnpSnappyBundle:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    false
        binary:     /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage
        options:    []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved installing a precompiled version. now you can get your version from here (inspired by [this](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/180#issuecomment-21317135) out of date answer ):

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

and changed my `config.yml` to:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    false
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
        options:    []
```

and now it works!

Comment: whats the difference between the above and below methods of installation and usage ?

Comment: @guy_fawkes - As `http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list` link doesn't exist anymore, I just installed `wkhtmltopdf` with an `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` command. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: The project URL have changed. The wget command should be done in the following address http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.0/wkhtmltox-linux-amd64_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz and to descompact the downloaded file use - tar -xJf wkhtmltox-linux-amd64_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz

Comment: The official precompiled versions return `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)` instead of `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4` as their version string (call `wkhtmltopdf -V`). Those patches do the trick to work without a (fake) X server. If you cannot use those binaries, you can try to use xvfb or xvfb-run to wrap the wkhtmltopdf-calls, if that is installed on your hosting environment (as it is at my hoster).

Answer (score 0):

You must copy it into directory : **/usr/local/bin**, make sur it's executable and add symlink of **wkhtmltopdf.sh** like :

1- the command :

```html
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

2 - insert the binary in directory **/usr/bin** so the browser can't have permission to execute in this directory.
You must copy the **wkhtmltopdf.sh**  to directory **/usr/local/bin** cause the browser have permission in this directory like:

```html
sudo cp /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

3 - After make sur the binary have permission of execution like :

```html
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

4 - so now you can test, it's work like:

```html
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

it make download the pdf in the current directory in your terminal

5 - Optional
now you can add symlink in your directory **/usr/local/bin** like

```html
ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

6 - copy to the **/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage** into **/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage** like:

```html
sudo cp usr/local/wkhtmltoimage usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

8- make sur this is executable too:

```html
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

7 - change the directory of binary in configuration of symfony in **config/packages/knp_snappy.yaml** :

```html
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    false
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
        options:    []
```

I Hope it's help you