# Installing WKHTMLtoPDF 0.12.x 64 bit on Ubuntu 12.04.5 (Dreamhost VPS)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, wkhtmltopdf, dreamhost

I'm trying to install WKHTMLtoPDf 0.12.x on a Dreamhost VPS running Ubuntu 12.04.5.  I found a realatively new [resource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server) and it seems like it should be pretty straight forward:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

But, it tells me the user I'm SSH'd in with using Putty is not in the Sudoers file, and the incident will be reported.

Is this the right way to install wkhtmltopdf on the Dreamhost VPS? and if so how do you add a user to the sudoers file?

I'm not overly savy with SSH commands or servers so any explanations would be best at a high-level.

**UPDATE**

Dreamhost was able to help me get on the sudoers list with no issues, but the commands listed above don't seem to work.  I'm at root after typing:

```
sudo -s
```

But now

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
ERROR - add-apt-repository: command not found
```

and

```
apt-get ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf (also tried it with just wkhtmltopdf)
ERROR - Invalid operation ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
```

I also tried

```
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Which installed wkhtmltopdf, but it installed version 0.9.9.3, which is super old.  How do I update this?  Or just get rid of it?

**UPDATE 2**

To remove the package and all its dependencies I used this [resource](https://gist.github.com/ermand/67a4ce7cf01f380c7e84):

```
apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf
```

and then as suggested by the command prompt ran autoremove afterwards to remove the dependencies.

```
apt-get autoremove
```

**UPDATE 3**

Okay, so through a coordinated effect this bit of [help](http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/) was found, so using:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

I can now use

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
```

And that allows the use of all the commands above (minus sudo if you typed "sudo -s")

**BUT** now I'm sitting in front of a freaky pink screen that is asking me to install Grub?  and I have no idea what I should do?  Should I say yes or no?  Why?

**UPDATE 4**

I SSH'd in using another shell to check if you have grub installed or not and by typing:

```
grub-install -v
```

I have 1.99-21ubuntu3.17, so I thought I'd hit no, but then it just keeps asking me to if I want to install Grub, which apparently is issue with this version of Ubuntu.  So I was forced to hit yes and everything seems to be working.

In case this was a bad decision to hit yes let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps taken to install WKHTMLtoPDF 0.12.x onto Ubuntu 12.04.5 derived from the above question, using these resources ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server) and [2](http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/)) where:

```
sudo -s
add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
```

If add-apt-repository is not a recognized command:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Continue if add-apt-repository was a recognized command, or after running the abov command to and rerunning the first command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

With regards to Grub, I don't know what you should choose.  For me it was made by the fact I couldn't say no, and had to choose yes based on some issue related to Ubuntu.

Once installed run:

```
wkhtmltopdf --version (should say wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1)
```

and then do a quick test of the install:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

If this results in a command not found error you'll have to install xvfb:

```
apt-get install xvfb
```

And run the command below (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604819/1148107)) to generate your PDFs:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing setup on AWS Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty AMD64 Machine i got lot of issues as wkhtmltopdf is not running at all, Giving Cannot connect to X server issue.
Finally the solution which worked for me is

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
$ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf
```