# How to get latest repository for WkHTMLtoPDF on Ubuntu 12.04.5 via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I figured out grab a version of WkHTMLtoPDF on my server using my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058340/1148107):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
```

But this is giving me version 0.12.1 and as of Jan. 19, 2015 version 0.12.2.1 has been released.  How do you specifically indicate the version of the repository you want to add-apt-repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that apt repository its the last version. Go to the website and download the newest version as deb file. Then install that file with

```
dpkg -i filename.deb
```

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: Where do I drop the file on my server? add-apt-repository is kind of like magic to me with regards to where things are placed.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` there are the sourced added in separated files.

Comment: Oh so where would you drop the .deb file?  /bin?

Comment: You don't need that file after installation. Install it with that command and delete the deb file.