# wkhtmltopdf and Meteor returning a blank pdf

Tags: meteor, wkhtmltopdf, iron-router

I'm generating a few html-based reports from my [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) app. Everything works beautifully on my development machine, but when I push it up to the server, the pdf files that are returned are empty.

I've installed wkhtmltopdf 0.11 using the instructions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15263815/2174991). I've also tried 0.9.9. When I go to print, I don't get any errors: just a pdf file without any content.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated!

Here's the code I'm using to generate the pdf:

```
Router.route('/reports/printHTML/:fileID?', {
   name: 'reports.printHTML',
   where: 'server',
   action: function(){

var headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=space_report_" + this.params.fileID + ".pdf"
};
this.response.writeHead(200, headers);

var wk = Meteor.npmRequire('wkhtmltopdf');

var thisReport = PastReports.findOne({_id: this.params.fileID});

if(thisReport){
  var html = thisReport.body + '<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="' + Meteor.absoluteUrl() + '/bootstrap.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.css"></head>';
  var r = wk(html, {pageSize:'letter', orientation:'Landscape', zoom:1, B:"5mm", L:"5mm", R:"5mm", T:"5mm",}).pipe(this.response);
} else {
  console.log("No report to print: " + this.params.fileID);
}
```

}
});

Comment: same here. did you solved it ?

Answer (score 2):

The user running your meteor app should have `wkhtmltopdf` in its `PATH`, so you might want to try the following:

- **Login as the user running your meteor app and verify the PATH where `wkhtmltopdf` is located** with either `which wkhtmltopdf` or `whereis wkhtmltopdf`
- **Login as the user running your meteor app and verify your PATH** with `echo $PATH`
- **Set your PATH to contain the same path that is used by `wkhtmltopdf`**

  `# inside ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile`

  `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`
- **Alternatively, you can create a symbolic link to `wkhtmltopdf` to an existing directory in your PATH.**  *If `wkhtmltopdf` is installed under `/usr/local/bin` and you already have `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`:*

  `ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Also, be sure to check the browser's console or server logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PhantomJS. The bundle included my OSX binary of phantomjs instead of Ubuntu version. 
As Chip suggested, try to change the path accordingly to your OS distribuction.

Comment: An example of the post-fix path would help