# wkhtmltopdf opens an application on OSX and doesn't finish its job till I focus this application

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, wkhtmltopdf

As far as I read wkhtmltopdf is using a patched version of Qt so that it can be executed WITHOUT using a graphical server such as Xorg, etc but when I run it in my OSX, it opens an application, it's visible in dock and when I press Command-Tab it's visible in list of applications shown, the icon of this app is a text "exec" in a black background. As soon as I focus this app it gets closed and wkhtmltopdf finishes its job but if I don't focus it, it doesn't finish its job at all.
Any ideas what can I do? I want it to run in background and respond automatically, I can't sit behind the system and Command-Tab each time a request is sent.

Update:
I tried it with an Ubuntu Server and it raises this error:

```
wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

when I try to run wkhtmltopdf directly in command line. Isn't it against to whole purpose of patching Qt so that it doesn't need an X server?

Answer (score 0):

It got solved after I faced the problem in Ubuntu, by searching the error raised in Ubuntu I could find this post [wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server) which seems led me to install the package from sourceforge (both in OSX and Ubuntu) and it solved my problem (both in OSX and Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You must copy it into directory : **/usr/local/bin**, make sur it's executable and add symlink of **wkhtmltopdf.sh** like :

1- the command :

```html
brew cask install wkhtmltopdf
```

2 - insert the binary in directory **/usr/bin** so the browser can't have permission to execute in this directory.
You must copy the **wkhtmltopdf.sh**  to directory **/usr/local/bin** cause the browser have permission in this directory like:

```html
sudo cp /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

3 - After make sur the binary have permission of execution like :

```html
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

4 - so now you can test, it's work like:

```html
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

it make download the pdf in the current directory in your terminal

5 - Optional
now you can add symlink in your directory **/usr/local/bin** like

```html
ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

6 - copy to the **/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage** into **/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage** like:

```html
sudo cp usr/local/wkhtmltoimage usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

8- make sur this is executable too:

```html
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

I Hope it's help you