# error to generate html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf after change parked server

Tags: apache, codeigniter

We have changed our parked server and before parked at new server script was working fine. but now script producing error

Server : ubuntu
PHP Framework : CI

Error is :

`Could not run command '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf' --margin-top '4' --margin-right '4' --margin-bottom '4' --margin-left '4' --page-size 'A4' /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_hGfaVM.html /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_wAkzvA: wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server`

Comment: possible duplicate, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to Codeigniter, but to the configuration of your server. (It might help to ask this question on Server Fault instead of Stackoverflow.)

1.) You should make sure that [xserver is installed and running](http://fedir.github.io/web/blog/2013/09/25/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu/) (it seems it's not.)

2.) As suggested by [mic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027762/mic) - Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server) too.

Hope this helps. Good luck!