# wkhtmltopdf with ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, wkhtmltopdf

**---- Introduction ----**

I was getting issues such as 'Warning : SSL Errors' while running the following command :
wkhtmltopdf -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 --javascript-delay 1000 --no-stop-slow-scripts --debug-javascript test.html output.pdf

Note that the above test.html runs some javascript over ssl / reverse proxy. Hence the SSL Errors..

**---- Command CURL, Testing Phase ----**

CURL command to test my certificate (without certificate) :

```
curl https://prod
```

Output :

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

CURL command to test my certificate (with certificate) :

```
curl https://prod --cacert cert.crt
```

Output :

```
<MY INDEX PAGE>
```

Takeway : Now I know the issue I have is to do with my remote machine certificate being selfsigned, I should be able to run my wkhtmlpdf command (assuming I can pass my certificate as an argument).

**---- Tool WKHTML, Implementation Phase ----**

The current build version I use is 0.12.4 (official release). It does not include ssl certificates support, so from there I have 2 options :

- option 1 : I wait until an official version gets released (0.12.5), and have tweeted this : https://twitter.com/DeepCashkette/status/889491206673223681+
- option 2 : I use a version that is more recent and potentialy unstable (wkhtmltopdf 0.13.0-alpha-7b36694).

I've opted for option 2, and downloaded wkhtmltox-0.13.0-alpha-7b36694_linux-precise-i386.deb and installed xvfb (required for alpha versions of wkhtmlX). Procedure here : [wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server)

I end up with this script "wkhtmltopdf.sh:

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf --ssl-crt-path cert.crt "$@"
```

However it still outputs : Unknown long argument --ssl-crt-path, and I cannot proceed to the (pdf) conversion.

Let me know should you need more technical details, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see no question.

Your test and implementation phases are inconsistent :

- `curl --cacert` is for server CA certificate
- `wkhtmltopdf --ssl-crt-path` is for client certificate

wktmltopdf ignores self-signed certificates [since v0.3](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG-OLD), so except a warning you don't need to pass any parameter in order to make wktmltopdf generate a pdf from your host.