# PHP wkhtmltoimage not working with shell_exec

Tags: php-7, wkhtmltoimage

I am trying to take screenshot like this:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage http://google.com screen.png");
```

But it is not creating screen.png. But when I run
  `/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage http://google.com screen.png` 
from terminal it works as expected. I am confused what is wrong.
I tried to write log like:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage http://google.com screen.png > debug.log 2>&1");
```

I get log "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)" on debug.log. I have php7.0 installed with Nginx on Ubuntu.
What would be the solution for this? Please share if someone solved the same.

Comment: Access rights, probably.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server. But working for pdf only. when I create png, jpg image, it created but blank image.