# How to converting web to pdf in pretty way

Tags: php, css, pdf, html2pdf, html-to-pdf

I have a problem with converting a web page (web url) to pdf. Some of CSS and the JavaScript not showing as I want >,<.

I've try some open source code like:

- dompdf
- html2pdf.fr
- html2pdf.it (which I've implement it)

The closest result as I want is html2pdf.it, but it's still not enough because some of CSS not showing correctly. [Example html2pdf.it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Qsl.png)

When I try to open pdfcrowd.com, it's show the result what I want.[Example pdfcrowd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMyKl.png) but we must paid for the service and the limitation problem.

I've tried to google and search how to  make it prettier, but until know I still didn't got the answer yet. >,<

Is there any other open source similar with them, or other things that I can do for it? I like their concept using url so I can use it with my other web based application using the api or triggered the link.

Comment: there's no 'pure' comparability between html and pdf it will always take some compromises.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I automate HTML-to-PDF conversions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176476/how-can-i-automate-html-to-pdf-conversions)

Comment: @Dagon i realize that, but the other people (someone like pdfcrowd) can make it prettier and i'm not. that's means i miss something right?

Answer (score 5):

HTML to PDF is tricky. I've tried most open source solutions, and they usually fall short in some aspect. 
If you are willing to pay, I use [docraptor.com](http://docraptor.com/), a very easy to use SaaS product with a reasonable price model(per month).
Internally it uses [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/), which is a very powerful HTML to PDF library, supporting various CSS3 features.

I have no affiliation to Docraptor or PrinceXML, just a happy customer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) its a very cool command line tool which makes a PDF from a website or a HTML file.

Comment: ah yes, i've try that one too... but i still get the problem with my header and chart problem >,< still looking the solution for it T_T